# Attach file send to email - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email

I have a controller

```php
public function contactsform()
{
     $this ->validate(request(), ['name'=>'required','phone'=>'required','email'=>'required','text'=>'required','file'=>'required']);
     $message = "Имя: ".request('name')."\nE-mail:".request('email')."\nPhone:" .request('phone')."\nFile:" .request('file');
     $subject = "Форма с сайта iten.kz";
     $headers = 'From: info@iten.kz' . "\r\n" .'Reply-To: info@iten.kz' . "\r\n".'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
     mail('015@i-marketing.kz', $subject, $message, $headers);
     return view('ru.page.contacts');
}
```

and my blade form

```
                    <form action="/contactsform" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                    <div class="order_form flex">
                        <div class="flex input_block">
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="order_input" placeholder="Имя*" required="">
                        <input type="text" class="order_input" id="phone2" name="phone" placeholder="Телефон*" maxlength="20" required="">
                        <input type="text" class="order_input" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" maxlength="20" required="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form_send">
                            <textarea placeholder="Задайте вопрос" name="text"></textarea>
                            <div class="flex add_block">
                                <div class="add add_file"><input type="file" value="Прикрепить файл" name="file"></div>
                                <div class="add add_txt"><span>Вы можете прикрепить файл заявке до 10 мб</span></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form_send_btn"><button type="submit" class="sub">Оставить заявку</button></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

I want to send input type file email but I don't know. Please help me to figure out how to send an email with an attachment.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a coding service website. Show us, what you have tried so far in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Laravel, do not use `mail` function to send mail. Laravel provides you with a possibility to use OOP power.

Generate mailable class using:

```
php artisan make:mail SendFormFromWebsite
```

To attach file, just call `->attach()` method.

Full documentation could be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mail#attachments)

*P.S. Do not send emails from the Controller. It should be stored and processed with a queue.*